# PHP POST multiple data inside one checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

i have following part of code:
`<input id="add" class="add" data-amount="150" data-monthly="25" type="checkbox" name="accessory[]" value="Accessory Name"/>`
wondering if there any way to post all data in "value", "data-amount" and "data-monthly" together to another script?

Comment: Without using jQuery or some JavaScript, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all those values in the checkbox, you can concatenate them together separated by some delimiter and then split the value when processing the form.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="accessory[]" value="Accessory Name*150*25"/>
```

This is not an elegant solution. It does what you ask, but you should strongly consider Sohnee's answer as a better method of doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing the value of those attributes onto the page server side, you are better off working off of a key and retrieving the values again server side based on the key. The HTML could be altered resulting in non-trustworthy data being send back.

For example...

```
<input id="add" class="add" data-amount="150" data-monthly="25" type="checkbox" name="accessory[]" value="1"/>
```

Where `1` is the id of the data that contains the amount and monthly data.

Comment: You beat me to this answer. I was almost done typing. I'd suggest this approach.

Comment: @SymenTimmermans sorry about that - I hate it when that happens! :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but unfortunately I can't retrieve the data again. Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.
I use OpenCart CMS and this checkbox is used to add items to order. Particularly it shows the page with accessories and user must check the ones he wish. After he press "Proceed" he will have an offer to buy it for cash or credit. That's where "data-amount" is showing the total price and "data-monthly" will show him a monthly payment for those products.
Seems that the best solution is to pass product_id in "value" and then make a connection to database.

Comment: @PhAbd but what if they change those values - if I change the HTML to `data-amount="0"` won't I get it for free?

Comment: The matter is that user cannot change that value. This "data-amount" is the actual price of the accessory taken from database according to product_id.
All i need is to cms generate an email containing all necessary data. Calculations are made earlier by the system

Comment: But they can use common debugging tools to change the value in the HTML, for example Firebug, Developer Tools, Dragonfly...

Comment: in this case system reports error and the order is not being processed)) all requests that are not made by the system are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes are not submitted with form data.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, however you can put all the attributes you need in hidden fields which are passed with form.